# how to get email body text while getting duplicate entry?

Tags: php, mysql, string, parsing, email

After mime parsing I am getting email body with duplicate entry(plain n html) and wondering how I can get the true message body. I am using php/mysql. Is there anything in php string or mysql to solve this?
email message body Sample:

```
testing body from hotmail. testing word can be repeated.



testing body from hotmail. testing word can be repeated.
```

Comment: Provide us with the program code and we might be able to help.

Comment: i believe you receive the message in double because the 1'st is actualy a ``plain/text`` message and the other it's ``text/html``. Most of email clients are sending in this format, the reason is very simple, not all email clients are able to display html emails.

Comment: @Mihai you are right. I am getting plain n html message. but how i can fix it. Is there any thing in php string or can i sort this through mysql database etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so as I said you receive the email in double because you receive it in `plain/text` and `text/html` format.

The best way to read email from pop3 as I found until now is [Manuel Lemos POP3 Access](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2-PHP-Access-to-e-mail-mailboxes-using-the-POP3-protocol.html)

the email formats ussualy are received in parts, for each type or image

`plain/text`:

```
------=_Part_38964_33016848.1312149074828
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
email content in text format
```

`text/html`:

```
------=_Part_38964_33016848.1312149074828
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
email content in html format
```

you will find in headers the name of the part, that unique identifier

```
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
              boundary="----=_Part_38964_33016848.1312149074828"
```

There isn't a simple way to get the real `plain/text` and `text/html`, they are most likely to be togheter if sent from  a public email service. If you send email from your scripts, I don't think you'll bother to send that email in double format.

Comment: My message content type is 'multipart/alternative'. How I can get 1 msg either plain(prefered) or html msg.

Comment: explode the message by part ID

Comment: Thanks for help. In the parser this content type was in array. so I picked first entry of array.